# Cannot read property "style" of null help. [Javascript, HTML, CSS, JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This project works perfectly fine on JSFiddle but when I compile it into a file it doesn't work.
Basically every thing that involves changing the "Style" gives an error in the source/console.

This is probably a simple error but I can't figure it out.

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enmydky4/

- Code -

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<head>
    <title> Color Test </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css.css">
    <script src = "jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascript.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <table id="Table">
        <tr id="Row1">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row2">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row3">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row4">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row5">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="Start">Start</div>
    <div id="Time"> Time: </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var Items = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var ItemNum = 0;
var Correct = 0;
var Time = 15;
var Random = function (Multiplyer) {
    return String(Math.round(Math.random() * Multiplyer));
};
var FuncRGB = function () {
    var RGB = [Random(255), Random(255), Random(255)].join(",");
    return RGB;
};
var ClearData = function(){
    ItemNum = 0;
    Correct = 0;
    Time = 15;
};

var StartTimer = function(){
    var Timer = setInterval(function(){ 
        if (Time > 0){
            Time = Time - 1;
            document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = "Time: " + Time;
        }else{
            alert("Finished" + "\n" + "Correct: " + String(Correct) + "\n" +  "Total: " + String(ItemNum) + "\n" + "Percentage: "  + (Correct/ItemNum)  * 100 + "%" );
            clearInterval(Timer);
            ClearData();
            StartGame();
        }
    }, 1000); 
};
var StartGame = function () {
    var StartScreen = document.getElementById("Start");
    StartScreen.style.display = "none";
    StartTimer();
    SetSquares();
};
var SetSquares = function () {
    var RGB = FuncRGB();
    var Different = Math.round(Math.random() * 24);
    for (var i = 0; i <= Items.length; i++) {
        if (i == Different) {
            Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(" + RGB + ",.8" + ")";
            Items[i].id = ItemNum;
        } else {
            Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + RGB + ")";
        }
    }
};
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("Start").onclick = StartGame;
}

$("#Start").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
$( "td" ).click(function() {
    $(this).toggle("bounce");
    if ($(this).attr("id") == ItemNum) {
        Correct = Correct + 1;
    }
    ItemNum = ItemNum + 1;
    SetSquares();
});



    var StartTimer = function(){
        var Timer = setInterval(function(){ 
            if (Time > 0){
                Time = Time - 1;
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = "Time: " + Time;
            }else{
                //alert("Finished" + "\n" + "Correct: " + String(Correct) + "\n" +  "Total: " + String(ItemNum) + "\n" + "Percentage: "  + (Correct/ItemNum)  * 100 + "%" );
                clearInterval(Timer);
                ClearData();
                StartGame();
            }
        }, 1000); 
    };
    var StartGame = function () {
        var StartScreen = document.getElementById("Start");
        //$(StartScreen).toggle( "bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow" );
        //StartScreen.style.display = "none";
        StartTimer();
        SetSquares();
    };
    var SetSquares = function () {
        var RGB = FuncRGB();
        var Different = Math.round(Math.random() * 24);
        for (var i = 0; i <= Items.length; i++) {
            if (i == Different) {
                Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(" + RGB + ",.8" + ")";
                Items[i].id = ItemNum;
            } else {
                Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + RGB + ")";
            }
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("Start").onclick = StartGame;
    $("#Start").click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
    $( "td" ).click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == ItemNum) {
            Correct = Correct + 1;
        }
        ItemNum = ItemNum + 1;
        SetSquares();
    });
```

Comment: You have the same functions twice ?

Comment: is your js code wrapped in a $(document).ready();?

Comment: So, was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a `document.ready` handler. The short way in jQuery would be to put your above code in between `$(function(){...})` like

```
$(function(){
var Items = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var ItemNum = 0;
var Correct = 0;
var Time = 15;
var Random = function (Multiplyer) {
    return String(Math.round(Math.random() * Multiplyer));
};
var FuncRGB = function () {
    var RGB = [Random(255), Random(255), Random(255)].join(",");
    return RGB;
};
var ClearData = function(){
    ItemNum = 0;
    Correct = 0;
    Time = 15;
};

var StartTimer = function(){
    var Timer = setInterval(function(){ 
        if (Time > 0){
            Time = Time - 1;
            document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = "Time: " + Time;
        }else{
            alert("Finished" + "\n" + "Correct: " + String(Correct) + "\n" +  "Total: " + String(ItemNum) + "\n" + "Percentage: "  + (Correct/ItemNum)  * 100 + "%" );
            clearInterval(Timer);
            ClearData();
            StartGame();
        }
    }, 1000); 
};
var StartGame = function () {
    var StartScreen = document.getElementById("Start");
    StartScreen.style.display = "none";
    StartTimer();
    SetSquares();
};
var SetSquares = function () {
    var RGB = FuncRGB();
    var Different = Math.round(Math.random() * 24);
    for (var i = 0; i <= Items.length; i++) {
        if (i == Different) {
            Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(" + RGB + ",.8" + ")";
            Items[i].id = ItemNum;
        } else {
            Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + RGB + ")";
        }
    }
};
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("Start").onclick = StartGame;
}

$("#Start").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
$( "td" ).click(function() {
    $(this).toggle("bounce");
    if ($(this).attr("id") == ItemNum) {
        Correct = Correct + 1;
    }
    ItemNum = ItemNum + 1;
    SetSquares();
});



    var StartTimer = function(){
        var Timer = setInterval(function(){ 
            if (Time > 0){
                Time = Time - 1;
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = "Time: " + Time;
            }else{
                //alert("Finished" + "\n" + "Correct: " + String(Correct) + "\n" +  "Total: " + String(ItemNum) + "\n" + "Percentage: "  + (Correct/ItemNum)  * 100 + "%" );
                clearInterval(Timer);
                ClearData();
                StartGame();
            }
        }, 1000); 
    };
    var StartGame = function () {
        var StartScreen = document.getElementById("Start");
        //$(StartScreen).toggle( "bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow" );
        //StartScreen.style.display = "none";
        StartTimer();
        SetSquares();
    };
    var SetSquares = function () {
        var RGB = FuncRGB();
        var Different = Math.round(Math.random() * 24);
        for (var i = 0; i <= Items.length; i++) {
            if (i == Different) {
                Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(" + RGB + ",.8" + ")";
                Items[i].id = ItemNum;
            } else {
                Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + RGB + ")";
            }
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("Start").onclick = StartGame;
    $("#Start").click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
    $( "td" ).click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == ItemNum) {
            Correct = Correct + 1;
        }
        ItemNum = ItemNum + 1;
        SetSquares();
    });

});
```

The reason it was working in your jsfiddle but not your actual site is because the fiddle was loading the script in the `onLoad` event.

In your actual site, you were including the script in the head, so the following line would fail

```
var StartScreen = document.getElementById("Start");
```

since there is not yet an element with id 'Start'